# Flutter Apple Sign in package is not returning the required credentials

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a Flutter app with Apple Sign In package: [Apple_Sign_In](https://pub.dev/packages/apple_sign_in) It seems to work fine, as it is signing me in. And it does provide a user id but the other credentials are all blanks see here:

```
{
credential =     {
    authorizationCode = "<FlutterStandardTypedData: 0x283033240>";
    authorizedScopes =         (
    );
    email = "<null>";
    fullName =         {
        familyName = "<null>";
        givenName = "<null>";
        middleName = "<null>";
        namePrefix = "<null>";
        nameSuffix = "<null>";
        nickname = "<null>";
    };
    identityToken = "<FlutterStandardTypedData: 0x283030560>";
    realUserStatus = 1;
    state = "<null>";
    user = "001061.cc1ba19b029c4da2a0b492026e586439.1240";
};
credentialType = ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential;
status = authorized;
}
flutter: YES SIGNED IN AND HERE ARE THE CREDENTIALS: null
flutter: USER EMAIL:: = quk98fwjws@privaterelay.appleid.com
flutter: USER NAME:: = null
```

Here is my code:

```
try {
  if (await AppleSI.AppleSignIn.isAvailable()) {
    final AppleSI.AuthorizationResult result =
        await AppleSI.AppleSignIn.performRequests([
      AppleSI.AppleIdRequest(
          requestedScopes: [AppleSI.Scope.email, AppleSI.Scope.fullName])
    ]);
    switch (result.status) {
      case AppleSI.AuthorizationStatus.authorized:
        print(
            'YES SIGNED IN AND HERE ARE THE CREDENTIALS: ${result.credential.email}'); //All the required credentials
        // NOW USE THE CREDS TO SIGN IN TO FIREBASE
        final appleIdCredential = result.credential;
        final oAuthProvider = OAuthProvider(providerId: 'apple.com');
        final credential = oAuthProvider.getCredential(
          idToken: String.fromCharCodes(appleIdCredential.identityToken),
          accessToken:
              String.fromCharCodes(appleIdCredential.authorizationCode),
        );
        final authResult =
            await _auth.signInWithAppleCredential(credential);
        print('USER EMAIL:: = ${authResult.email}');
        print('USER NAME:: = ${appleIdCredential.fullName.familyName}');
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this as Apple will not release my app to the app store without it having the Apple sign in completed.

Many thanks and if you have any questions do not hesitate to contact me, I hope I have provided enough information.

Carson

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is working as intended

Apple only returns the full name and email on the first login on the device for your app, it will return null values for these on any login after that. My guess is that you've signed in previously and then tried to sign-in again via a new Firebase Auth user and the Name/Email is no longer available at that point.

For testing purposes, to receive these again; go to your device settings; **Settings > Apple ID, iCloud, iTunes & App Store > Password & Security > Apps Using Your Apple ID, tap on your app, and tap Stop Using Apple ID**. You can now sign-in again and you'll receive the full name and email again.

This is how Apple has designed their API - so it's recommended that you store these elsewhere on your app, e.g. using the shared_preferences plugin - so that you consistently have access to them when required.

Comment: Fundamentally flawed: If the user reinstalls your app, the credentials will be gone, but the sign-in session is still alive. So you have to store the generated user ID somewhere in clear text in your DB, because this is all that will be send by the client. This is bad practice, but it's the only way to recover the session without the users having to remove it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still have problems with apple sign in, this plugin has been discontinued.

Use `firebase_auth_oauth: ^` with firebase to authenticate, get the user's email from firebase user, just do it ...

```
    User? user = await FirebaseAuthOAuth().openSignInFlow("apple.com", ["email"], {"locale": "en"});
```

And then get the data from the user like...

```
 var email = user.email;
```